# Twitter API 1.1 get direct messages "Your credentials do not allow access to this resource" error code 220

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

```
<?php  
    require_once('twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php');
    require_once('config.php');
    require_once('function.php');
    header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); 



    // Datadan kullanıcı çekiliyor
    $a = mysql_query("select * from users WHERE twid = 326960131");
    $i=0;
    while ($b = mysql_fetch_array($a)) { 
        $oauth_token[$i] = $b["oauth_token"]; 
        $oauth_secret[$i] = $b["oauth_secret"];
        $tid[$i]=$b["twid"];
        $connection[$i] = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $oauth_token[$i], $oauth_secret[$i]);
        //Tüm bilgilerin kaynağı alınıyor
        $bilgi[$i] = $connection[$i]->get('account/verify_credentials');

        $i++;
    } 
    // -------------------------


    // Tweetpost döngüsü
    for ($i=0;$i<count($tid);$i++) {
        $screen_name = $bilgi[$i]->screen_name;
        $profilresmi = $bilgi[$i]->profile_image_url;
        $kullaniciid = $bilgi[$i]->id;
        $takipcisayisi = $bilgi[$i]->followers_count;


        $tweet = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access, $secret);

        $followers = $tweet->get('direct_messages', array('count' => '1'));

        print_r($followers);

    }
    flush();
?>
```

When I try to run this codes It says

```
> stdClass Object ( [errors] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [message] => Your credentials do not allow access to this resource [code] => 220 ) ) )
```

I want to get direct messages of selected user. But it says like that. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible problems.

1. Are you the authenticating user?  Using the API you can only get your own messages.
2. Check the permissions of your app on https://apps.twitter.com/ - did you request DM access, or read-only access?

Comment: 1. "Are you the authenticating user? Using the API you can only get your own messages." I didnt understand this.
2. My permissions is "Read, Write and Access direct messages"